# jquery callback doesn't work

Tags: jquery, callback

The $.getJSON method returns data, but callback doesn't execute.I switched off, same origin policy in my browser, and I see through my proxy that response returns form server.
Any Idea what is wrong ?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.0.js">
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                   $("#callServerBtn").click(function (event) {
                       $.getJSON('http://www.miazipcimem.info/api', function (data) {
                           alert(data.ip);
                       });
                   });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Click on the button to load json data:</p>
    <input type="button" id="callServerBtn" value="Load Data"/>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can't use ajax here because server doesn't allow cross domain request. You could proxify it server side but...

Comment: How did you know that server doesn't allow  cross domain request ? Actually server returns valid json..                              UPD: However it works with other servers fine.. probably you are right.. can you please give me a hint how do determine whether server supports cross origin apis or not ?

Comment: Looks like it dosn't work at all..

Comment: This is what this error message means in console: "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." Server return json, not jsonp. What do you mean by: "Looks like it dowsn't work at all.." ? What doesn't work?

Comment: Do you happen to be running this from the file:// protocol or the http:// protocol?

Comment: I run it from file:// protocol ..